# How to move content of Content editor webpart from Development to UAT server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have developed one master page,layout page and some content page based on these master and layout page. 5 content editor web and 4 visual web part part are included in each content page.I have developed all these things in my development environment.Now my task is to move all these to UAT environment.

I can move master page, layout page and visual webpart easily but my problem is, how to move content of content editor webpart.Do i have to manually copy paste content of content editor webpart from dev environment to UAT or i can use some tool or technique to save this manual effort.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you are moving the master page and web parts manually, so if that is your case you can export the content editor and add it as a web part in "UAT"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. But my problem is to move content that i have written in content editor in dev environment.like i have written <p>ABC</p> in "conten editor1" in "DEV" now i want to move this content editor to "UAT" with same data <p>ABC</p>. I do not want to add content editor in page in "UAT" and just paste again my html(<p>ABC</p)

Comment: well, when you export the web part you are not exporting it as a content editor, but you are exporting it as new web part type with your inner content intact.
Try using some features to deploy your web parts and custom pages, that would make them more portable and professional.